# GQL: Comparison operator doesn't work

Tags: gql

i am trying to execute a GQL query on a location dataset stored in Datastore. Here's some example data:

```
Name/ID | latitude | longitude
------------------------------
- location1 | 34.4104149048 | -116.850200484
- location2 | 34.4118891533 | -116.865934048
- location3 | 34.4146973835 | -116.847347137
```

However, this GQL query doesn't return any results:

```
SELECT * FROM Location WHERE latitude > 1.0
```

As a simple GQL query where I select all items of type Location works, I am wondering what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I am executing the query via the Datastore web interface, so it cannot be the code.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out by myself:
I didn't [create an index](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig?hl=de) for the latitude and longitude properties, which is apparently needed to query over these properties...